# Ansible win_uri module doesn't return content for POST query

Tags: windows, ansible, uri

I try to get some data from the page after the POST query. I'm using ansible 2.9.10. But the win_uri module in it doesn't return the content of the response. But Invoke-WebRequest working on the same host.

```
  win_uri:
    method: POST
    url: "{{ configuraton_url }}"
    body: "{'action': 'listconfig'}"
    validate_certs: no
    use_default_credential: yes
    return_content: yes
  register: configuration
```

result

```
  configuration:
    cache_control: private
    changed: false
    character_set: null
    content: ''
    content_encoding: ''
    content_length: '0'
    content_type: ''
    cookies: []
    date: Mon, 29 Jun 2020 20:17:29 GMT
    elapsed: 0.1875025
    failed: false
    headers:
    - Persistent-Auth
    - Content-Length
    - Cache-Control
    - Date
    - Server
    - WWW-Authenticate
    - X-AspNet-Version
    - X-Powered-By
    is_from_cache: false
    is_mutually_authenticated: true
    last_modified: '2020-06-29T20:17:29.5951209+00:00'
    method: POST
    msg: OK
    persistent_auth: 'true'
    protocol_version:
      Build: -1
      Major: 1
      MajorRevision: -1
      Minor: 1
      MinorRevision: -1
      Revision: -1
    response_uri: https://xxxxxxx:xxx/xxxxxxxx
    server: xxxxxxx
    status_code: 200
    status_description: OK
    supports_headers: true
    url: https://xxxxxxx:xxx/xxxxxxxx
    www_authenticate: Negotiate oRswGaADCgEAoxIEEAEAAAAyRzN6JblgagAAAAA=
    x_asp_net_version: xxxxx
    x_powered_by: xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> content_length: '0'
> ```

It's doing exactly as the server instructed, there is no content returned

No one on Stack Overlow will be able to tell you why your obfuscated server did not return any content, but ansible is doing as it was instructed

---

As a **guess**, I would guess you are sending a malformed payload, both that `body:` should have the quotes reversed (since the single-quote version is legal python, but not legal JSON) and you are missing the [`content_type: application/json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/win_uri_module.html#parameter-content_type) in order to tell `win_uri:` not to use `x-www-form-urlencoded`. We can't know for sure that's what's happening because you removed the rest of the module output

```yaml
  win_uri:
    method: POST
    url: "{{ configuraton_url }}"
    body: '{"action": "listconfig"}'
    content_type: application/json
```

Comment: Same result with content_type. And  Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell works perfectly and returns content.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. But found this article: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34698 and discovered that I had not used the return_content parameter. The default is to NOT return the content.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/win_uri_module.html#win-uri-module

After adding "return_content: yes" the task was working as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can see in my question  this option is present`return_content: yes`. At that moment, it didn't work. For now, I can't check it because doesn't have any Windows servers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31295995)